# How to use $toLower and $trim aggregation operators using MongoDB Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I have a collection called Users, which contains an array called skills.

I use the following code to unwind the skills array and count the number of documents associated with each skill:

```
Bson uw = unwind("$skills");
Bson sbc = sortByCount("$skills");
Bson limit = limit(10);
coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(uw, sbc,limit)).forEach(printDocuments());
```

Now I want to make use of **$trim** and **$toLower** operations for the above aggregation because in the database, some skills saved in different ways (e.g., **"CSS"**, **"CSS "**, and **"css"**).

I'm able to do this in the mongo shell with the following aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$unwind:"$skills"} , {$sortByCount:{$toLower:{$trim:{input:"$skills"}}}}])
```

But I'm having troubles with implementing it in Java.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `$trim` and `$toLower` are Aggregation string operators. These can be used (in your case) within the `$addFields` _or_ `$project` stages.

Comment: @prasad_ I can use them without `$addFields` or `$project` in mongo shell with this aggregation: `db.users.aggregate([{$unwind:"$skills"}, {$sortByCount:{$toLower:{$trim:{input:"$skills"}}}}])` but I'm struggling with implementing it in Java. Can you help me with this?

Comment: MongoDB Java's [Aggregates.sortByCount](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.html#sortByCount(TExpression))

Comment: @prasad_  This method has a parameter: `filter` and my problem is `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters` class does not contain neither $trim nor $toLower. Also I tried `sortByCount("$toLower:{$trim:{input:"$skills"}}")` but it's not working.

Comment: After the `$unwind` stage you can add a `$addFields` stage and use the operators `$trim` and `$toLower` - and there should not be any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to do this with changing the sortByCount to the following:

```
Bson sbc = sortByCount(eq("$toLower", eq("$trim", eq("input", "$skills"))));
```